# Overriding delete() vs using pre delete signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have a model where i would like when an object gets deleted, instead of being deleted a status is updated. This was achieved with following code:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    self.status = Booking.DELETED
    self.save()
```

The manager was updated so that in the rest of the application i never get presented deleted bookings.

```
class BookingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(status=Booking.DELETED)

class BookingDeletedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
         return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Booking.DELETED)

class Booking(models.Model):
    PAYED = 0
    PENDING = 1
    OPEN = 2
    CANCELLED = 3
    DELETED = 4
    objects = BookingManager()
    deleted_objects = BookingDeletedManager()
...
```

Now i have read up on django signals and was wondering wheter it would be better to use the pre delete signal here. The code could be changed so that in the pre delete receiver a duplicate is created with status 'deleted' and the original booking is just deleted.

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) it states that these signals should be used to *allow decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework*. It seems the signal is a good a solution but this nuance in the documentation makes me think it's maybe not what i want and overriding might just be the way to go.

This is not really the case here since i just want this functionality all the time. **So my question being is there a solid reason why i should not override the delete method and use the pre delete signal or vice versa?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the documentation it states that these signals should be used to allow decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework.

That's indeed the point: allowing one application to get notified of events occuring in another application *that knows nothing about the first one* - hence avoiding the need to couple the second application to the first one.

In your case using models signals instead of just overridding the model's method would be [an anti-pattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/): it will only add overhead and make your code less readable for absolutely no good reason, when the very obvious solution is to just do what you've did.

Comment: Please note that overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods. However, when using the pre_delete signal, one cannot stop the deletion. I'm not sure what the correct way is to circumvent this.

Comment: @gabn88 note that signals are not invoked on raw sql queries nor on queries made outside the orm / project either ;-) - if you want something that will always be executed however the row is deleted, you want a database trigger.